# Having issues fitting random forest classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using IPython's UI with appropriate libraries (Anaconda, pandas, numpy)

I've declared a pandas object df, I've changed it so that the first column is the desired value I wish to predict but my code still continues to stop at line 10. Line 11 does not run. Instead, the Terminal IPython window quits and displays this error:

```
~/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3: 45581 Killed: 9               ~/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Start of code

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)

In [4]: cols = list(df)

In [5]: cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Cover_Type'))) %Cover type is column I wanted to bring to column position 1 or value I'm predicting

In [6]: cols

In [7]: df = df.ix[:, cols]

In [8]: df

In [9]: forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)

In [10]: forest = forest.fit(train_data[0::,1::],train_data[0::,0])

In [11]: output = forest.predict(test_data)

In [12]: train_data = df.values

In [13]: train_data
```

Comment: Where train_data comes from? What is dimensions of train_data? Maybe this error caused by sort of memory limitations?

Answer (score 1):

You are using train Data in line 10 which is not available. You assign it later on.

First assign train data , then use it in forest.fit